# send mail to gmail ssl problem in c#

Tags: c#, ssl, gmail

i try to send me an mail via c# but everytime it comes an ssl error. can you tell me whats wrong?

Thank you

```
SmtpClient mail = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("address", "address");
msg.Subject = "send data";
msg.Body = "Stuff";
mail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw");
mail.Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";

Attachment data = new Attachment(path1);
msg.Attachments.Add(data);
Attachment data2 = new Attachment(path2);
msg.Attachments.Add(data2);
Attachment data3 = new Attachment(path3);
msg.Attachments.Add(data3);

mail.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gmail+c%23) at least once?

Comment: it comes the error:  Server answer: 5.3.2 Sorry, during probation period you are not allowed to use SMTP service {mp018}

Comment: http://img5.imagebanana.com/img/4g931soo/Unbenannt.png look here

Comment: The error is self-explanatory and has nothing to do with SSL.

Comment: @GregS, sry i'm new with c#, can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
mail.EnableSsl = true;
mail.Port = 587;
```

Comment: it comes the error:  Server answer: 5.3.2 Sorry, during probation period you are not allowed to use SMTP service {mp018}

Answer (score 1):

> it comes the error: Server answer: 5.3.2 Sorry, during probation period you are not allowed to use SMTP service {mp018}

From this error I'm assuming you've just signed up for the google account, and google is not allowing you to use its smtp service until its probation period is over. Find out how long the probation period is and try when its over

Comment: i have my account over 4 years and its activated in the settings :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [`mail.EnableSsl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx) to `true`.